# Looking for an online community specializing in the Z specification language, where I can ask questions

Tags: reference-request, formal-methods

Where can I find an online community specializing in the Z specification language, where I can ask specific questions about the ISO standard for Z?

Comment: Try here and see what you get ;-)

Comment: May be, you can look in the web site of the Z user group (http://zuser.org/).

Comment: @CyriacAntony: Thanks. I tried looking there, but the site seems not to have been updated in years. All linked usenet/Google groups are either defunct or have fallen out of use.

Answer (score 1):

There is the comp.specification.z newsgroup, available on [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.specification.z).

There are some mailing lists:

- [ZFORUM mailing list](http://www.jiscmail.ac.uk/ZFORUM)
- [Zed Freelists mailing list](https://www.freelists.org/list/zed)

Additionally, there are mailing lists for tools that support the Z notation.  For tools that support ISO Z (or a similar dialect), I doubt anyone would object to a question about the notation itself if the above sources are not useful.  For example:

- [Community Z Tools (CZT) mailing lists](https://sourceforge.net/p/czt/mailman/)
- [ProofPower mailing list](http://lemma-one.com/mailman/listinfo/proofpower_lemma-one.com)

Comment: The Google group is not active in years. The others I need to check.

Comment: Did you try posting to comp.specification.z?  Many lists appear inactive because there is so little interest in the Z notation.